# Float label with select2

Tags: jquery-select2

I currently have pure css driving the float labels. I was wondering if there was a way to apply the float label to select2. Basically keeping select2 but having the label float.

```
 <div class="col-sm-3 border-right floating-label">
                        @{ int? dropDownClientID = (Model.LR.ClientID == 0 ? (int?)null : Model.LegalRequest.ClientID); }
                        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.LR.ClientID, Model.ClientSelectList.OrderBy(x => x.Text), "", new { @id="buyerSelect", @form = "legalRequestForm", @class = "floating-select2", onclick = "this.setAttribute('value', this.value);", value = @dropDownClientID })
                       
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LR.ClientID, new { @class = "label-e-test" })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LR.ClientID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

                    </div>
```

CSS

```
        .label-e-test {
            color: #999;
            padding-top: 7px;
            font-size: 1.12em;
            font-weight: normal;
            position: absolute;
            pointer-events: none;
            left: 5%;
            top: 5%;
            transition: 0.2s ease all;
            -moz-transition: 0.2s ease all;
            -webkit-transition: 0.2s ease all;
           
        }

        .floating-select:focus ~ label,
        .floating-select:not([value=""]) ~ label.label-e-test {
            top: -7px;
            left: 8px;
            font-size: 10px;
            font-weight: 600;
            color: #5264AE;
            padding-top: 4px;
        }
```

select2

```
$('#buyerSelect').select2({
         
    });
```